# Thin black bar appears on fullscreen Flash videos in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, flash-player

In Chrome, when I go fullscreen on YouTube videos I get a thin horizontal black line across all videos, about 2/3 of the way up the screen. It looks like this:

[image: line on screen]

It isn't there when the video is reduced to normal size. It only happens in Chrome, not other browsers.

Then, on all Vimeo vids, when fullscreen I get letter \ pillar boxing around the vids. It looks like this

[image]

This happens on all Vimeo videos fullscreen in Chrome - the black bars disappear in normal size reduced screen. It isn't there in other browsers.

I'm running Win 7 64 bit. I'm using Chrome v 44.0.2403.155 (Official Build) m (64-bit)

What is causing this?

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded the Google Chrome beta client and the bar isn't there any more.